# Jetpack compose WindowsInsets does not apply on Preview

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

Using WindowsInsets([android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/insets)) in app with jetpack compose, doesn't show on @Preview.

Here my `Modifier.windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.safeContent)` does not apply as Preview.
If I replace windowsInsetsPadding with padding(24.dp) it's apply as preview.

I feel like the Preview doesn't know about WindowsInsets of the current device selected in preview.
Maybe `WindowsInsets` is not intented to be used on Preview?

```kotlin
@Composable
internal fun SignInRoute(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: SignInViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    SignInScreen()
}

@Composable
internal fun SignInScreen(
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.safeContent),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        // Content ...
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
private fun SignInScreenPreview() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Surface(
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {
            SignInScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenShot]

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/316195049) open in the Google Issue Tracker that is asking for this exact functionality. The issue still is open, but was assigned to an employee, so I think what you are asking for is not yet possible. You can upvote the issue or ask in a comment about the situation to draw more attention to it.